# Domain Redirection via htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I just added an addon domain to my shared hosting and cPanel also created a subdomain under my primary domain leading to the addon domain that I just have added.

I do not want the user to be able to access my secondary website under the new addon name via the subdomain to my primary domain that cPanel created (addon_name.primarydomain.com). That is why I decided to create a simple .htaccess file which will redirect automatically any user trying to access the addon_name.primarydomain.com to my primarydomain.com

```
#Redirecting if the URL is encrypted
RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} ^addon_name\.primarydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ https://primarydomain.com/? [L,R=301]

# Redirecting if the URL is NOT encrypted.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^addon_name\.primarydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://primarydomain.com/? [L,R=301]
```

However while running this code I found the following issues and due to the fact that I am not very experience with .htaccess I would be really grateful if someone could explain what I am doing wrong.

1) When I try to enter addon_name.primarydomain.com it redirects me to primarydomain.com = WORKS.

2) When I try to enter http://addon_name.primarydomain.com it redirects me to primarydomain.com = WORKS.

3) When I try to enter www.addon_name.primarydomain.com it doesn't want to redirect me to primarydomain.com = ERROR.

4) When I try to enter http://www.addon_name.primarydomain.com it doesn't want to redirect me to primarydomain.com = ERROR.

5) When I try to enter addon_name.primarydomain.com/something/index.html it redirects me to primarydomain.com/something/index.html instead of just primarydomain.com  = ERROR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this slightly modified version is what you want to express:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} (^|www\.)addon_name\.primarydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://primarydomain.com/ [QSD,R=301]
```